# Show that the set of R-Algebra homomorphisms is Hausdorff

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, commutative-algebra

For an $\mathbb{R}$-Algebra $P$, let $M(P)$ be the set of $\mathbb{R}$-Algebra homomorphisms $\lambda: P \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, w.r.t the initial topology generated by evaluation maps:
$$  \{ev_a : M(P) \rightarrow \mathbb{R};   \lambda
\rightarrow \lambda(a)  \}_{a \in P}$$

How do you show that $M(P)$ is a Hausdorff Space?

Trying to figure this out, but am stuck.

Comment: Are you sure that this question belongs to the algebraic topology tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By construction of the topology on $M(P)$, evaluation maps are continuous.

Suppose that $\lambda \neq \lambda' \colon P \to \mathbb{R}$ are distinct $\mathbb{R}$-algebra maps from $P$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and note that this occurs precisely if they are different *functions*. Hence we have some $x \in P$ for which $\lambda(x) \neq\lambda(x')$. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff, there are disjoint open sets $U_\lambda \ni \lambda(x), U_{\lambda'} \ni \lambda'(x)$ and so

$$
U = ev_x^{-1}(U_\lambda), \quad V = ev_x^{-1}(U_{\lambda'})
$$

are disjoint open sets separating $\lambda$ from $\lambda'$.

In general, we have shown that if $X$ is a Hausdorff space and $S \subset X^Y$ is a subset with some topology for which evaluation maps are continuous, then $S$ is also $T_2$. There is no need for the algebraic structure of $M(P)$ to make this argument work.

Comment: Thank you, I feel dumb, I am just starting out on this in an undergrad alg top class :). This was left as an optional exercise, I should have spent more time before asking this here though :/.